# Kali Linux Boot error pcieport... ( After boot only shows an static "_")

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, kali-linux

I tried installing Kali on my pc recently (a few times by now ) but it just dosnt work. I tried it on my laptop and it works perfecly fine. I never get past the loading screen or at least not how expected. After I select Kali Linux in grub I get the follwing error

**The error:**

```
pcieport 0000:00.ic.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
pcieport 0000:00.ic.4: AER:   device [0006:a294] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
pcieport 0000:00.ic.4: AER:      [ 0] RxErr
```

To be honest I have no idea what to do anymore, I used Windows until now so I'm not experienced at all. After the loading sreen this shows for a split second which is just a cut version of the above. After that there only is a static "_" (not pulsing)

```
pcieport 0000:00.ic.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, t
pcieport 0000:00.ic.4: AER:   device [0006:a294] error status/mas
pcieport 0000:00.ic.4: AER:      [ 0] RxErr
```

**Further info:**

Mainboard: PRIMAL Z370-A

- secure-boot = disabled
- fast-boot = disabled

GPU: 2080ti strix

CPU: Intel 8700K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. I faced a similar problem with Ubuntu. I believe a missing graphics card driver caused the issue described above. When running into a similar issue with Ubuntu I tried to start the PC in safe mode, so no divers where loaded and I managed to get into a terminal. At this point I installed the latest Nvidia driver for my OS, restarted the machine and now everything seems to work fine.